# How to modify a value in the array in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The following is the code which I am using for creating a two dimensional array

```
Public Class frmGrades
Private Score As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub cmdApply_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdApply.Click
    Static intNumber As Integer
    ReDim Preserve Score(1, intNumber)
    Score(0, intNumber) = txtStudent.Text
    Score(1, intNumber) = txtGrade.Text
    hsbStudent.Maximum = intNumber
    hsbStudent.Value = intNumber
    intNumber = intNumber + 1
    txtGrade.Clear()
    txtStudent.Clear()
    txtStudent.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub hsbStudent_Scroll(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles hsbStudent.Scroll
    txtStudent.Text = Score(0, hsbStudent.Value)
    txtGrade.Text = Score(1, hsbStudent.Value)

End Sub

Private Sub cmdFirst_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdFirst.Click
    txtStudent.Text = Score(0, hsbStudent.Minimum)
    txtGrade.Text = Score(1, hsbStudent.Minimum)

End Sub

Private Sub cmdLast_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLast.Click
    txtStudent.Text = Score(0, hsbStudent.Maximum)
    txtGrade.Text = Score(1, hsbStudent.Maximum)
End Sub

**Private Sub CmdEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdEdit.Click

    If Score.ContainsKey(txtStudent.Text) Then
        Score.Item(txtStudent.Text) = txtGrade.Text
    Else
        Score.Add(txtStudent.Text, txtGrade.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class**

Now I would like to edit the grade text box which should also change the grade in the array. Any idea on how could this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

OK, I see the code has a little more now and the problem is more clear as well as the need for a different approach. I rewrote your code. See if this works for you:

```
Public Class frmGrades

    Public Class StudentGrade
        Public Name As String
        Public Grade As String
    End Class

    Private Score As List(Of StudentGrade) = New List(Of StudentGrade)

    Private Sub cmdApply_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdApply.Click

        AddStudent()

    End Sub

    Private Sub hsbStudent_Scroll(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles hsbStudent.Scroll
        Update(hsbStudent.Value - 1) 'lists are zero-based
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdFirst_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdFirst.Click
        Update(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdLast_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLast.Click
        Update(hsbStudent.Maximum - 1)
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddStudent()
        Dim nm As New StudentGrade
        nm.Name = txtStudent.Text
        nm.Grade = txtGrade.Text
        Score.Add(nm)

        hsbStudent.Minimum = 1
        hsbStudent.Maximum = Score.Count 
        hsbStudent.Value = Score.Count 

        txtGrade.Clear()
        txtStudent.Clear()
        txtStudent.Focus()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Update(i As Integer)
        txtStudent.Text = Score(i).Name
        txtGrade.Text = Score(i).Grade
    End Sub
    Private Sub CmdEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdEdit.Click

        Dim index As Integer = -1, cnt As Integer = 0

        For Each nm As StudentGrade In Score
            If nm.Name.ToLower = txtStudent.Text.ToLower Then
                index = cnt
                Exit For
            End If
            cnt += 1
        Next

        If index = -1 Then
            AddStudent()
        Else
            Score(index).Name = txtStudent.Text
            Score(index).Grade = txtGrade.Text
            hsbStudent.Value = index + 1
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

With this code you can expand the class StudentGrade to contain whatever you need to store. The list, contrary to dictionary, allow you to use index values as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the edit is a new button itself . so do you think I can still use the dictionary there. The code I pasted above was to feed values in the array. Now I want to change any value and then click on the edit button to change those values in the array.

Comment: Certainly, if you put the dictionary reference in class level you can refer it from any of your buttons within the same class.

Comment: Ok, lets see - What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error message? (please post). I'll edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: Senthil, I saw in my original answer that I had left a "student" value instead of txtStudent.Text. Please replace if you're using the code as-is. I have updated the original example.

Comment: For redim statement it gives me an error "Redim requires an array."
Also for the txtStudent.Text it say too many arguments

Comment: I updated the code. See if that works for you - modify as needed.